# Google map marker update with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had this working when data was coming from static factory. Now data comes in from an AJAX call (`$http`) from a remote server and for some reason markers dont get put on the map.

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CWk9pLC492PKyJuYzzpC?p=preview)

Basically if I uncomment `$http` and replace the static data, it will not show up. It will show variable `markers` filled with right data, just wont populate the map

Kind of similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618612/ui-gmap-markers-is-not-working)

Comment: Try with ng-if and setting mode.state to true after the first batch of markers has been loaded, ng-show messes with ui-gmap in my application and positions it wrong

Comment: mode.state is true. Map is clearly visible, markers are not

Comment: Found similar problem, trying to figure out from this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372161/using-ng-repeat-with-markers-in-ngmap

Answer (score 0):

i mean setting mode.state to true after the markers are loaded:

```
$scope.mode.state = false;
$scope.change_type = function(val) {
    var markers = [];
    $scope.eventMarkers = markers  // clear the map of markers, before loading new

    Events.venues(val.type).then(function(resp){
        var venues = $.map(resp.data, function(value, index){return [value]})  
        for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
            event = venues[i]
            markers.push(createMarker(i,event))
        }
        console.log(markers)
        $scope.eventMarkers = markers
        $scope.mode.state = true;
    }, function(errror){
        console.debug(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried ng-if, it gives me some strange error: ` Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.` However it doesnt change anything, i had it working just fine with ng-show for static data from the factory.